# Voltage drift in lock in amplifier

Tags: amplifier

I am testing out the lock in amplifier with just a single resistor, but there seems to be a downward drift in the in phase voltage. What could possibly cause this to happen? Could it be some grounding issue?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be real- you could be heating the resistor with the applied signal and you could be seeing the temperature coefficient of the resistor.